# Object gets darker when I zoom in to the object

Tags: lighting

So I have a sun in my scene and the point of that sun is to give some moonlight to the scene. I have the sun on grayish color with the intensity of 40W but when I zoom in to the object effected by the light it becomes dark. Does anyone know why?
[image: This happens when i zoom in]

Comment: I've tried to answer your question, it looks like you don't use a _Sun_ object as light. However I'm not yet sure how zooming in could change the light on the object. Does your lamp move with the camera? Does the object move?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a *Point* light (or maybe a *Spot*) as light source in your scene. If it were a *Sun* than a value of 40 would be extremely bright, also a sun's strength value would be shown as a decimal 40.000 without a *W* for watts.

Go to the light settings and switch from *Point* (or *Spot*) to *Sun*. Or delete the light source and add a new *Sun*.

Comment: There is only a sun to light up that area, there are other lights in the scene but that is only to light up a room also I tried to hide it and it's still the same. The sun's intensity is 40 but to compensate the color is dark gray. Also if I change the color to white and intensity to 1 or 3 it still has the same effect. After doing some things, when I hide my cloud which is just a 2d texture with the displacement modifier and my stars which is a dome with a hair particle system with the particle being a small object that emits a bit of light, the bug stops happening.

Comment: For the stars and clouds I follow a tutorial from CG Geek on youtube about making a night sky.

Comment: Is the darkening caused by a shadow of the cloud?  Maybe it would help if the question already provides the information that there are other objects in the sky... And why do you set such a high value for the sun that you have to make it dark grey? Why not make it white (or a faint blue for moonlight) and reduce the strength to something quite low?

Comment: Your thoughts about the sun is a good point, but the sun is below the stars and cloud. Also when I set the color to white and then make the intensity 3 it's still the same

Comment: My comment on the strength of the sun was independent from the cloud shadow. I usually use a strength between 1 and 5 for bright sunlight... so if you want to make moonlight why not use lower values? You might get away with 0.1 to 0.5 for the strength. But for the shadow: a _Sun_ is not like a _Point_  or _Spot_ lamp. Its position doesn't matter, it's working like a light source outside of the scene. Only the rotation determines the direction of its parallel light rays. Which means, every object in the scene casts a shadow, even if it's positioned "behind" the sun object.

Comment: Good point, but how can I make light pass through the cloud and the sphere dome for the stars?

Comment: I don't know how your cloud and sphere dome are set up, so I can't tell. But clouds usually cast shadows...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123271/discussion-between-uhmzzzzmmmm-and-gordon-brinkmann).

Comment: sphere dome? We rarely ever use these with raytracing renderers (and when we do, it's because it's mostly fully a transparent dome with a few semi-opaque motives like a few clouds), that's a very old way of working. I suggest you to not use that. We have a world shader to do that, or use mesh planes behind your scene if you really want to use images in your scene to fake landscapes. But anyhing that can only prevent the engine from rendering light is basically working against you.